# Receiving 404 for maven-metadata.xml from Artifactory remote repo of repo.grails.org

Tags: maven, artifactory, remote-repository

I am trying to setup the https://repo.grails.org/core repository as a remote repository on my artifactory instance.  If I use that URL directly in the configuration, I can pull everything except the maven-metadata.xml.  Maven will throw an error saying it got a 404 for it, and I can verify that by trying to manually pull it through my remote repo.
I have also tried setting up the remote as a smart remote, entering just https://repo.grails.org/artifactory.  It will recognize it as an artifactory server, but if I hit Test I get a 500 error.  Saving the settings the repo shows no artifacts.
I have also tried https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/core, /artifactory/api/core, /artifactory/api/maven/core, /grails/core as well as a few others and those that work for retrieving jar or pom files still give a 404 for the maven-metadata.xml.

What is the correct way to configure the repo.grails.org repo as a remote repository?

I have tried this is both the 7.29 and 7.3 versions of artifactory with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our previous experience, it was understood that grails repository `core` that you are pointing to is a virtual repository. grails admins might have added all the remote and local repositories under this. But artifactory does not support virtual repositories for smart remote repositories. You may need to point to the correct path.
You may try to point to `https://repo.grails.org/core` and then can you share the full path of the file that you are trying to download and facing the issues right now.

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks! I ended up creating 13 or so remote repos that represented the local or remote repos under the core virtual repo and grouping them back together on my artifactory instance with a virtual repo locally.

Comment: Great. That's the workaround we have.